# Convergence of finite rank operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $B$ be a real/complex Banach space.

Let $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a finite rank operators on $B$, and $T$ be a compact operator on $B$. We assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty}T_nu=Tu$ in $B$ for any $u \in B$. Then, can we show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}T_n= T$ in the sense of operator norm?

Comment: We can't. Take $B = \ell^2$, $T = 0$, and $T_n$ suitable rank-1 operators.

Comment: Then how can we show that $\|T_n - T\| \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ in the operator norm?